# Docker and NodeJs - Not Available in browser

Tags: node.js, docker

I installed an nodejs based image via docker compose and it seems that it all works fine, but I cannot access it in browser. I tried with `localhost:4200`, with `127.0.0.1:4200` and even with the ip I got from `docker inspect` I couldn't access it.

Here's the part of my docker-compose.yml

```
frontend:
    image: johnpapa/angular-cli
    container_name: frontend
    command: npm start
    working_dir: /usr/app
    volumes:
      - /home/USER/dev/angular-frontend/frontend-app:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
```

The output on docker run says `** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **` and the container is up and running when I check with `docker ps`.

What do I have to do to access it in my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your docker container's network is different from your host's.

You need to make your node process listen on all interfaces, by binding it to 0.0.0.0 rather than 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Comment: I did not bind it to localhost and if i run docker ps it is bind to 0.0.0.0. But still, how do I access it in my browser then?

Comment: Try entering your container and running `netstat -ntpl` from there

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4200          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      38/ng

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:32879        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -`

Comment: `tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:4200 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 38/ng`
See? node is listening on 127.0.0.1 inside your container. This will never be reachable from your host networking space.

Comment: Hm, ok, strange. Didn't do anything like that. So in my docker-compose I have to set it to 0.0.0.0:4200:4200 right?

Comment: Nope, that controls how you bind your port listening inside your container to a port in your host. You need to work inside the docker container itself.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will find out how to do that. Thanks. :)

Comment: Ok, I actually have no idea. Could you give me a hint on how to do that? All other containers are automatically bind to 0.0.0.0 only this one is bind to 127.0.0.1

Comment: It really depends on the source code of your app. What's the `npm start` script?

Comment: Ha! Actually this was enough to point me in the right direction. I got it! Thanks man, was having trouble with it since days. :)

Comment: great, glad I helped